# Android get image to Bitmap from filepath

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmapimage

I'm trying to set the image from a specific filepath ON THE PHONE. The filepath  is to the photo on the phone. the filepath could look like this 
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.jpg

Here is the code.

```
Bitmap image = null;

//trying to set the image from filepath
try {
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(filepath).getContent());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (image == null) {
    //This becomes true because the image is not set
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"image == null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

In the end the image is not set.

Comment: Is it `URL` or a `URI`?

Comment: better use `AsyncTask` to download image from url.

Comment: the image is on the phone and not on the internet

Comment: can you post `imgurl`? Its actually a filepath. isn't it?

Comment: @Boss you are right, it's a filepath :)

Comment: Use `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)`

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use This Method to get Bitmap from Filepath

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {
Bitmap bitmap=null;
try {
    File f= new File(path);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
return bitmap ;
}
```

Comment: the image is on the phone and not on the internet

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File imageFile = new File(sd+filepath);
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
 }});
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
 Uri targetUri = data.getData();
 textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
 Bitmap bitmap;
 try {
  bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
  targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```